# Trying to find time travel pulp story about traveller who gives proto-Inca the wheel which allows them to resist Europeans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, pulp

Trying to find a short story. Probably Astounding or Analog. Guy goes back in time to early South America. Shows locals how to use the wheel. Then tries to go forward in time. Story ends with Incan or Aztec priest/prince waiting on top of a temple for the prophet to appear. meanwhile off in the distance the locals' jets are fighting those of European invaders.

Comment: To put it another way -- when did *you* first read the story? Even if you suspect the story was written a couple of decades before you stumbled across a copy, that could still give us some sort of timeframe.

Comment: Thanks. I think 1970s or very early 1980s. And I'm pretty sure it was Analog.

Answer (score 8):

I found it. It was "[The Ninth Circle](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50959)" by Robert B. Marcus, Jr., Analog August 1974 at page 33. It's also available in an anthology called [*Memories of Darkness*](https://amzn.to/3dXqIF4), and the author has an excerpt [here](http://www.morningsidepublishing.com/thedarknesstocome.htm).

> An agent from the future is sent into the past to retrieve a scientist who holds the key to mankind's future.

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.